# Why is this empty?

Tags: postgresql, fuzzy-search, supabase, supabase-database

Please does anyone know why this:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('an');
```

returns nothing but

```
SELECT to_tsvector('nn');
```

or

```
SELECT to_tsvector('n');
```

or

```
SELECT to_tsvector('aa');
```

do?

I am testing this on PostgreSQL 13 running on SUPABASE.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because "an" is a *stop word* in your current setup (probably English, the default).

From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/textsearch-controls.html)

> The to_tsvector function internally calls a parser which breaks the document text into tokens and assigns a type to each token. For each token, a list of dictionaries (Section 12.6) is consulted, where the list can vary depending on the token type.

And (emphasis mine)...

> Some words are recognized as stop words (Section 12.6.1), which causes them to be **ignored since they occur too frequently** to be useful in searching.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks!, really appreciated it;